# Angular data binding - ng-book claims you should bind by object attribute. why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

“it’s considered a best-practice in Angular to bind references in the views by an attribute on an object, rather than the raw object itself.”

Excerpt From: Ari Lerner. “ng-book.” (page 66 in the latest revision).

I've not seen this reference anywhere else and wonder if it really makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It's to avoid child scoping issues. There are weird things with the scope on angular objects. Basically, there is scope inheritance for objects on scopes, but not for primitives. Here's a problem I've had.

```
<input ng-model="theModelOnMyScope" />

$scope.theModelOnMyScope = "This is the model";
```

Looks fine right? But in some cases it won't update on the scope in the controller you're editing because angular may create a childScope for the ng-model in input, depending on how your page is structured. Now, this is the solution to this particular problem.

```
<input ng-model="anObject.theModelOnMyScope" />

$scope.anObject = {theModelOnMyScope:"This is the model};
```

And this will work. The reason is it will is because, if the referenced property on the view is a property of an object, Angular will try to find an object on the current scope, and if it can't, it will go UP a level and try to find an object on the scope's parent. So you can make use of scope inheritance with objects. It doesn't do that with primitives, for some reason. So to avoid child scoping issues, it's just best to attach your properties to objects.

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense but I'm surprised there isn't a more official response somewhere.